# VBA access to a json property without name property

Tags: json, vba

I'm trying to access in VBA to over 508 "tank_id"s from a JSON file [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxhk9.png).

I'm using cStringBuilder, cJSONScript and JSONConverter to parse the JSON file.

My main issue is that I can't pass threw all those ids because I don't know how to get the "1" "33" "49" "81" that are without names.

Here si the code I tried to get them, without success.

```
Const myurl2 As String = "https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/encyclopedia/vehicles/?application_id=demo&fields=tank_id"

Sub List_id_vehicules()

Dim strRequest
Dim xmlHttp: Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
Dim response As Object
Dim rows As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim j As String
Dim k As Integer: k = 2
Dim url As String

url = myurl2
xmlHttp.Open "GET", url, False
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
xmlHttp.send
While Not xmlHttp.Status = 200            '<---------- wait
Wend
Set response = ParseJson(xmlHttp.ResponseText)
rows = response("meta")("count")

For counter = 1 To rows
    j = counter
    Dim yop As String
    yop = "data[" & j & "][" & j & "]"
    Sheets(2).Cells(1 + counter, 1).Value = response('data[counter]')['tank_id']
Next counter

END Sub
```

Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JSONConverter` essentially parses the JSON text string into a set of nested `Dictionary` objects. So when the `ParseJson` function returns an `Object`, it's really a `Dictionary`. Then, when you access `response("meta")`, the "meta" part is the `Key` to the `Dictionary` object. It's the same thing as you nest down through the JSON.

So when you try to access `response("data")("3137")`, you're accessing the `Dictionary` returned by `response("data")` with the `key="3137"`. Now the trick becomes how to get all the `Keys` from the `response("data")` object.

Here's a sample bit of code to illustrate how you can list all the tank IDs in the JSON data section:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListVehicleIDs()
    Const jsonFilename As String = "C:\Temp\tanks.json"

    Dim fileHandle As Integer
    Dim jsonString As String
    fileHandle = FreeFile
    Open jsonFilename For Input As #fileHandle
        jsonString = Input$(LOF(fileHandle), #fileHandle)
    Close #fileHandle

    Dim jsonObj As Object
    Set jsonObj = ParseJson(jsonString)

    Dim tankCount As Long
    tankCount = jsonObj("meta")("count")

    Dim tankIDs As Dictionary
    Set tankIDs = jsonObj("data")

    Dim tankID As Variant
    For Each tankID In tankIDs.keys
        Debug.Print "Tank ID = " & tankID
    Next tankID
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked great for what I wanted.
I'm so grateful to you helping me.
A huge thank you.

The fact was that I did not know how to use dictionary. Got an example now.